# Printing without showing on the print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, printing

I need to print customer password on double layer paper using a special thermal printer which the operator can not see the password on the cover paper, while the customer can separate two papers and see her/his password on the underneath.
I want to print the password (say a span element) using `CSS`, `HTML` and `javascript` without showing it to the operator.
The print preview displays the password.
How can I do this?
Or any other solution.
**Update:**
We have some limitation, including no internet access to use google cloud or other internet resources and as I know we can not avoid print preview in browsers as well.

Comment: Perhaps print password in white color?

Comment: I did that but it is displayed on the print preview.